# What is the value of $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i(g) X_i(h^{-1})$ when $g,h \in G $ are in the same conjugacy class?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I know the value of this summation $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i(g) X_i(h^{-1})$ when $g,h \in G $ are in the different conjugacy class will be zero and I know how to prove it but what about if they are in the same conjugacy class??
Where $X_i$ is the character.

Comment: But it's the same as $\sum \chi_i (g) \chi_i(g^{-1})$, since $h^{-1}$ and $g^{-1}$ are in the same conjugacy class. Can you evaluate the former sum?

Comment: Is it equals to n?

Comment: Yes, from your other question.

Comment: I see, Thanks again

Comment: @ Sanchez: my professor said that is not correct because the index of this sum is $i=1 ... s$ while the index of other qeusition is $g \in G$. I don't know! what do you think?

Comment: Your teacher is right, I misread the indices. In that case, use your other question to get that the character table is an orthogonal matrix (after you suitably normalize each term). If the other question was column orthogonality, this one would be row orthogonality.

Comment: Or more simply, note that it's the sum of the trace of $g$ acting on $Hom(\rho_i, \rho_i)$ if $\rho_i$ accounts for all irrep of $G$. But $\oplus Hom(\rho_i, \rho_i) = \mathbb{C}[G]$, so you are looking for the trace for $g$ acting on the group algebra. This is $|G|$ if $g=1$ and 0 otherwise.